# print a pdf file embedded in web page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a pdf file embedded on a web page. I want to put a print button the web page so that the end user can print the pdf file. How can I achieve this. below is the code for embedding the pdf file on web browser:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())

        {

            string embed = "<object data=\"{0}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"1000px\" height=\"1000px\">";

            embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}\">here</a>";

            embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";

            embed += "</object>";

            TempData["Embed"] = string.Format(embed, "/FilledPDFFiles/Confidentiality Statement" + ".pdf");

            return View();

        }
```

the code is in .net core MVC, razor pages, c#

Comment: the problem is users are not technically savvy. i need to put the print button at the bottom of the page where pdf is embedded.

Comment: the users are company employees, but there are some who doesn't know much about computers. I can see the print button at the top of the pdf file, but I am asked to put a print button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways you could follow:

**The first way** is that suggest you can use `<iframe>` instead of `<object>` and use js/jquery to print the file.

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    string embed = "<iframe id=\"printf\" src=\"{0}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"1000px\" height=\"1000px\">";

    embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}\">here</a>";
    embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
    embed += "</iframe>";
    TempData["Embed"] = string.Format(embed, "/pdffile/test" + ".pdf");
    return View();
}
```

Js code:

```
<button onclick="PrintPDF()">Print this pdf</button>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        function PrintPDF() {
            window.frames["printf"].focus();
            window.frames["printf"].contentWindow.print();
        }
    </script>
}
```

**The second way**, if you must use the `<object>`, you need use js/jquery like below:

```
<button onclick="PrintPDF()">Print this pdf</button>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        function PrintPDF() {
            var url = $("object").attr("data");   
             $('body').append('<iframe src="'+url+'" id="printf" hidden></iframe>');
             window.frames["printf"].focus();
             window.frames["printf"].contentWindow.print();
        }
    </script>
}
```